# Python equivalent for matlab's perms

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

Is there an equivalent method in numpy or scipy for matlab's perms function? In matlab, perms returns a matrix of all possible permutations of the input in reverse lexicographical order.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a built-in function called `itertools.permutations`. You can call it on any `iterable` in python and it returns all full length permutations.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a more detailed example because it was not clear to me how to implement it with the first answers:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools    
MyArray = np.arange(3)
permut = itertools.permutations(MyArray)
permut_array = np.empty((0,3))
for p in permut:
    permut_array = np.append(permut_array,np.atleast_2d(p),axis=0)
```

This returns a numpy array of permutations:

```
>array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is similar to previous answers but it returns the array in reverse lexicographical order to more closely match MATLAB's `perms`.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def perms(x):
    """Python equivalent of MATLAB perms."""
    return np.vstack(list(itertools.permutations(x)))[::-1]
```

Usage:

```
In [1]: perms(range(3))
Out[1]:
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```